Evaluating square roots of quartic powers
I wonder why Mathematica does not act on the powers inside square roots. See the following example:
Sqrt[a^4 b^4 c^4 d^4] does not give
a^2 b^2 c^2 d^2]

rather it returns back
Sqrt[a^4 b^4 c^4 d^4]
as the output.
Can someone comment on this?

Simplify[Sqrt[a^4  b^4  c^4  d^4]]

Gives
Sqrt[a^4 b^4 c^4 d^4]

Now
Assuming[Element[{a, b, c, d}, Reals], Simplify[Sqrt[a^4  b^4  c^4  d^4]]]

Gives
a^2 b^2 c^2 d^2

Mathematica works in complex domain by default. A simple example
a = 6*I;

Now
Sqrt[a^4]
(* 36 *)

But
a^2
(* -36 *)


I think PowerExpand is what you need as in
PowerExpand[Sqrt[a^4  b^4  c^4  d^4]]
(* a^2*b^2*c^2*d^2 *)

